# How can I adhere tile to a painted wall?

Tags: tiling

How do I get tiles to adhere to a wall which was painted with kitchen latex paint?  Paint has proved to be impossible to remove.  Was thinking of applying Zinsser Gardz to seal over as some of the paint is lifting slightly.  Would appreciate some advice.

Comment: If the paint is lifting, no primer will help with that. You *must* scrape any loose material off the wall before proceeding.

Comment: "Paint has proved to be impossible to remove" seems contradictory to "paint is lifting slightly" ... Unless you remove the paint, your tiles will be not be stuck to the wall, but stuck to the paint (for what that's worth).

Answer (score 1):

If the wall surface is solid, free of contaminants, us a mastic and go right over the painted wall, after you scratch it up a bit with sandpaper to give the mastic a slightly rough surface to grip to.

This is presuming the wall is above a countertop not subject to getting saturated with water to affect the drywall backing.